# Getting JavaFX WebEngine Interpreted Document

Tags: javafx, domdocument, javafx-webengine

Calling the getDocument() method on the WebEngine object for me only returns the source retrieved from the server, without the JavaScript being executed (there are still  elements).  This is the kind of source you would see if you used "View Source" in Chrome.  How do I retrieve the interpreted source with the JavaScript already run?

```
public Browser() {
    WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    webEngine.load("*******************************");

    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
                printDocument(doc);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the following: the `LoadWorker`'s state is set to `SUCCEEDED` before JavaScript is done running. JavaScript **does** in fact run (as shown in @James_D's reply) but there is no callback to signal when it finishes. AFAIK, there is no reliable way to detect when the WebEngine is done executing JS.

What you could do as a workaround is play a `PauseTransition` after the state changes to SUCCEEDED, which can be abused to act like a `sleep` on the JavaFX thread (JS is executed in the background thread that also loads the Document, so JS will not pause). However, sleeping (to wait for JS to finish) is inherently a violation of JavaFX's core principle **never** to block the UI thread. On top of that, waiting for a period of time does not guarantee that JS is done executing before that period passes.

I've faced the same problem and I have not found a decent solution. Let me know if you do!

Comment: For a better solution see **Calling back to Java from JavaScript** here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html. And add the self executing Javascript-Code to the end of your HTML-Page.

Answer (score 2):

This works as expected for me. In this example, the `div` contains a text node with the text that is set by the Javascript function:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class WebViewOnLoadExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine()
            .getLoadWorker()
            .stateProperty()
            .addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
                if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    Document doc = webView.getEngine().getDocument();
                    showNodeContent(doc, 0);
                }
            });
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(webView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

        webView.getEngine().loadContent("<html>"
                +"<head><script>"
                +"function setText() {"
                +"  document.getElementById(\"target\").appendChild(document.createTextNode(\"Hello World\"));"
                +"}"
                +"</script></head>"
                +"<body onload='setText()'>"
                +"<div id='target'></div></body></html>");
    }

    private void showNodeContent(Node n, int depth) {
        for (int i=0; i<depth; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(n.getNodeName()+":"+n.getNodeValue());
        NodeList children = n.getChildNodes() ;
        for (int i=0; i<children.getLength(); i++) {
            showNodeContent(children.item(i), depth+1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... It works for me.  I'll see if I can modify my original code and find where they diverge.

Comment: Actually, it appears that the JavaScript is being executed.  However, there are strings in the graphical version of the webpage which I can't find in the DOM.  Do you know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting your question right, but if you are looking for a way go print the visible content of the web you are loading, getting the `DocumentElement` from `Document` will allow you to dive into its structure and filter what you need.

This method will print the content of the desired tags:

```
private void printElement(Element el, int level){
    NodeList childNodes = el.getChildNodes();
    for(int j=0; j<level; j++) System.out.print("-");
    System.out.print("tag: "+el.getNodeName());
    if(el.getNodeName().equals("A")){
        System.out.print(", content: "+el.getTextContent());
    } 
    System.out.println("");
    for(int i=0; i<childNodes.getLength(); i++){
        Node item = childNodes.item(i);
        if(item instanceof Element){
            printElement((Element)item, level++);
        }
    }
}
```

so once you've loaded the URL, just call it:

```
if(newState==State.SUCCEEDED){
    Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
    Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
    printElement(el,0);
}
```

This will print all the DOM tags with their level of indentation, and for the tag specified, it will print also the content. In this case, with the tag "A" it will print the content of all the links.

I'm not sure if this will help. Please clarify your question otherwise.

Comment: No, this is not the issue.  I have no problems printing out the Document.  It's that the **content** of the Document which is wrong; it still contains the <script> elements instead of running the JavaScript.

Comment: Note that the scripts will be always loaded with the page, and if you access the DOM you will find these scripts. Do you mean that part of the javascript is still loading or pending while the load status say `SUCCEEDED`? Knowing these scripts will allow you execute them if that's the case... Could you specify what are you trying to get accessing the DOM?

Comment: In the webpage you want to load there could be some scripts that are not necessary executed on load, but triggered later by some other events. You could call any of them from JavaFX or even insert your own scripts to add more funtionality. Note also that the DOM is changing after any of these scripts are executed, so you need to check again its content. Since you're not providing more details on your question is really difficult to say...